# connection to the C server using LWIP stack

Tags: c, client-server, ethernet, lwip

I want to connect my micro-controller with normal C server using LWIP stack and without using Real time operating system.

Is it possible??

I have looked through 
http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Raw/TCP link

and test the following code:

```
void my_client_init(void)
{
   struct tcp_pcb *pcb;
   struct ip_addr dest;
   err_t ret_val;
   IP4_ADDR(&dest, 192, 168, 1, 10);
   pcb = tcp_new();
   tcp_bind(pcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, 8889); 
   tcp_arg(pcb, NULL);
   ret_val = tcp_connect(pcb, &dest, 8888, client_connected);
   if (ret_val != ERR_OK)
   {
   UARTprintf("\tcp_connect(): Errors on return value, returned value is %d\n", ret_val);
   }
}
```

but its not connecting to the server.

Now I have changed this to the below code as bind() and connect() should have same port number:

```
   struct tcp_pcb *pcb;
   struct ip_addr dest;
   err_t ret_val;
   IP4_ADDR(&dest, 192, 168, 1, 11);
   pcb = tcp_new();
   tcp_bind(pcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, 8888);
   tcp_arg(pcb, NULL);
   ret_val = tcp_connect(pcb, &dest, 8888, client_connected);
   if(ret_val != ERR_OK)
   {
   UARTprintf("\tcp_connect(): Errors on return value, returned value is %d\n", ret_val);
   }
```

Even i have used the lwip_init() below writing the above code but the tcp_connect() is returning error of -4 which implies Routing problem.
what else i should include in the code??

Comment: Yes it is : http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/LwIP_with_or_without_an_operating_system

Comment: You should have added what you tried, where you looked, etc., but it seems I did not read the site terms... here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before ... here the only thing we can answer you is "yes" it is, you can do what you want with [tag:c], except ride unicorns.